# how to use function to all row in html document

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace string `& amp;LF;` with `< br>< /br>` tags.

in paragraph:

```
<p id="adres" class="p1">aaaaa&amp;LF;aaaaa&amp;bbbbb&amp;LF;bbbbb&amp;LF;< /p>
```

using funtion:

```
var str = document.getElementById("adres").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("&amp;LF;", "<br/>");
document.getElementById("adres").innerHTML = res;
```

I call this function in body tag as:

```
<body onload="myFunction();">
```

But it replaces only first row.

How can I replace all rows in html document I got?

Comment: Use `regex` with `replace` with `g` flag

Comment: can you please post full html data?, i am not sure what do you mean by "only first raw" here.

Comment: @Ripun it replace only the first occurrence of `&amp;LF;`

Comment: ok so i guess you have multiple paragraphs in the html document, can you please provide your html (atleast 3 or 4 instances of <p>) where i can test my code ?

Comment: you need to replace var res=str.replace("&amp;LF;", "<br/>"); with var res = str.replace(/&amp;LF;/g, "<br/>"); then it will work for all occurrences of &amp;LF;

Comment: @Ripun thanks, var res = str.replace(/&amp;LF;/g, "<br/>");  works fine. Can you tell me how can I use it to few paragraphs?

Comment: welcome :), sure but can you please tell me what is the common between all paragraphs in your page meaning classname or something like that ?

Comment: Well, all paragraph all the same and using the same classname.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is for a single element. So it should change the value for that particular element.

if you want to use `id` try something like;

```
id='adres1'
id='adres2'
id='adres3'
```

and in function

```
var str,n, xy;
for(n=1; n<4; n++)
{
xy =  "adres"+n;
str = document.getElementById(xy).innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("&amp;LF;", "<br/>");
document.getElementById("adres").innerHTML = res;
}
```

this is to get you started, you can make the code neater than this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the replace function to the following, which includes the global replacement option `/g`. It should work.

```
var res = str.replace( /&amp;LF;/g,"< br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

first update your replace code by

```
var res = str.replace(/&amp;LF;/g, "<br/>");
```

since you all the paragraphs are containing the same class name then you can simply fetch all the

element in one variable and iterate through it.

please refer below fiddle example to see working code

http://jsfiddle.net/py3dzzrv/

Comment: I don'tknow what I'm doing wrong but it doesn't work. How to call function from fiddle? Should I still use <body onload="myFunction();"> ? Sorry, I'm suck in js and haven't use this language ever.

Comment: actually fiddle will call it automatically on "onLoad" event you don't have to call any function for that(in case of fiddle ), while in your page the code will remain as is as you have now, just replace the logic of your myFunction(); with the one i have provided in JsFiddle

Comment: ohh well...everything is ok in html but I have problem with XHTML, cause it treats "<" as an invalid tag while I want transform document to html type.

Comment: Loop for doesn't work when I use &lt; instead of "<" or when I put script in CDATA sections

Comment: please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Properly_Using_CSS_and_JavaScript_in_XHTML_Documents#Using_CDATA_Instead_of_Comments

Comment: After transformation my script looks like : //
function myFunction() {
var para = document.getElementsByClassName("p1");
for(var i = 0; i &lt; para.length; i++)
{
  var str = para[i].innerHTML; 
 var res = str.replace(/&amp;amp;LF;/g, "&lt;br/&gt;");
 para[i].innerHTML = res;
}
}
//

Comment: try below script   // <![CDATA[
 var para = document.getElementsByClassName("p1");
for(var i = 0; i < para.length; i++)
{
  var str = para[i].innerHTML; 
 var res = str.replace(/&amp;LF;/g, "<br/>");
 para[i].innerHTML = res;
}
// ]]>

Comment: or what you can do is write your java script code in external .js file then include it in your html, that will also work